# Page turn effect curl animation in webview?

Tags: android, animation, webview

I have created animation for page turning. but animation not same like curl animation. have you any idea to give webview animation for page turning curl animation. or any other animation.

please suggest me. or have you any code than please tell me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are checking animation like this.[image]

Check this for more [page curl animation](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/pageflip_android.php)

Comment: yes i want to this type of animation but i want to apply animation in webview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of software did you use to create the page turning animation. But I find this one, you can embed animation in webpage with simple codes. Refer to http://www.flippagemaker.com/faq/embed-flash-in-existed-webpage.html.

It seems that if you are using the FlipBook Creator (http://www.flippagemaker.com/flippingbook-maker/), you can directly publish flipbook animation into html web view-able format.